# How to generate random password code without using rand function in Classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic

I am using rnd function in Classic ASP to generate a random number password for the user, however, Veracode scan captured it as a bug and it is required to be fixed. Is there a way, I could possibly use some other 256 symmetric technique to generate a password. Searched a lot but could not find in classic ASP. Also, they suggest to use the COM wrapper class and call it from ASP after creating its object. I'm not sure how to do this. I have read the tag below but could not find a way to do it. If you could provide a step by step process how to proceed, would be really helpful? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

One of possible way:

```
<%
    Set X = Server.CreateObject("System.Random")    
    For I = 1 To 10 
        Response.Write Chr(48 + X.Next_2(0, 10))
    Next
    Set X = Nothing
%>
```

Will return ten randomly generated numbers

Comment: Ah. Probably because if I run it ten times in a row it generates the exact same number ten times